# 'NoneType' object is not iterable when working with API Pagination

Tags: python, json, api, nonetype

I am trying to create some code that establishes an API connection, iterates through all the pages, and returns a list of data. The frustrating thing is that this code sometimes works without any issues but sometimes I receive the dreaded **'NoneType' object is not iterable** typeerror. Both my code and the error message can be seen below.

```
import json 
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
import os.path
import schedule
import time


def eRelo_schedule():
    parameters = {
    "CreatedAfterUTC": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
    "RecordsPerPage": 2000
    }
    
    headers = {
    "Content-Type" : "application/json",
    "Authorization": str('AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN'),
    }

    referrals = []

    pagenum = 1

    while True:
        url = f"https://restapi.erelocation.net/api/v1/GetReferrals?PageNum={pagenum}"
        print("Requesting", url)
        resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=parameters)
        data = resp.json()
        for item in data.get('Referral', []):
            if len(data['Referral']) == 0:
                print(done)
        referrals.extend(data['Referral'])
        pagenum = pagenum + 1


schedule.every(24).hours.do(eRelo_schedule)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Last time I ran the code, I made it to page 48 before I received the error below. Any thoughts on how I can avoid this issue in the future? Thanks!

```
Requesting https://restapi.erelocation.net/api/v1/GetReferrals?PageNum=47
Requesting https://restapi.erelocation.net/api/v1/GetReferrals?PageNum=48
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14912/3600745513.py in <module>
     43 
     44 while 1:
---> 45     schedule.run_pending()
     46     time.sleep(1)

~\Anaconda3\envs\LeadsAnalysis\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py in run_pending()
    778     :data:`default scheduler instance <default_scheduler>`.
--> 780     default_scheduler.run_pending()
    781 
    782 

~\Anaconda3\envs\LeadsAnalysis\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py in run_pending(self)
     98         runnable_jobs = (job for job in self.jobs if job.should_run)
     99         for job in sorted(runnable_jobs):
--> 100             self._run_job(job)
    101 
    102     def run_all(self, delay_seconds: int = 0) -> None:

~\Anaconda3\envs\LeadsAnalysis\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py in _run_job(self, job)
    170 
    171     def _run_job(self, job: "Job") -> None:
--> 172         ret = job.run()
    173         if isinstance(ret, CancelJob) or ret is CancelJob:
    174             self.cancel_job(job)

~\Anaconda3\envs\LeadsAnalysis\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py in run(self)
    659 
    660         logger.debug("Running job %s", self)
--> 661         ret = self.job_func()
    662         self.last_run = datetime.datetime.now()
    663         self._schedule_next_run()

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14912/3434317735.py in eRelo_schedule()
     28         resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=parameters)
     29         data = resp.json()
---> 30         for item in data.get('Referral', []):
     31             if len(data['Referral']) == 0:
     32                 break

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Sounds like 'Referral' is actually in the dict and its associated value is None, so your attempt to default that to empty list doesn't work. The key would need to be absent. Ideally, your API wouldn't yield a property with a None value, but I think you'll have to check for it explicitly. Or use `for item in data.get('Referral') or []:`

Answer (score 0):

You should log the response's body in order to understand what's going on, but it looks like the API is returning something like `{"Referral": null}`, `{"Referral": 0}` or any non iterable value.

As a solution, you could check the type before iterating:

```
resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=parameters)
data = resp.json()
if data and 'Referral' in data and isinstance(data['Referral'], list):
    for item in data['Referral']:
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately even with all the changes, the error still occurs. How should I go about logging the response's body? I am somewhat new to python.

Comment: If the error still occurs it must mean that _data_ is `None`. I slightly modified my above answer to check for this case.

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to do the trick.

Comment: I may have spoke too soon. The code worked successfully a few times and now I am receiving the error again.

Comment: Do you receive the same exact error as in your first post: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` ?

Comment: Yes, This is what I receive:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
`TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_25856/105085086.py in <module>
     27             if len(data['Referral']) == 0:
     28                 print("done")
---> 29     referrals.extend(data['Referral'])
     30     pagenum = pagenum + 1

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`